# Select without from clause as subquery in select (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with two tables, Transactions and Customer. The Transaction table has transaction dates, Customer ID, and other transaction information. The customer table has Customer ID and other customer information. I need to find a count of transactions made by each customer. Even if a customer made two transactions in one single date, the count will be one.

I was writing a query to get the distinct count of transactions from a column. At first, I used the following query with a from clause in the subquery but it was not working. Accidentally, I removed the from clause, `right join (Select Customer.customer_Id) Customer`, and it gave me the right answer. I am not able to understand why?

```
Select 
   Customer_Name as [Customer Name], Gender,
   (select COUNT(distinct tran_date) from Transactions
        right join (Select Customer.customer_Id) Customer
        on Transactions.cust_id = Customer.customer_Id) as [Basket Count]
from Customer
```

The result table is something like

```
+---------------+--------+--------------+
| Customer Name | Gender | Basket Count |
+---------------+--------+--------------+
| Bob           | Male   |            2 |
| Jenny         | Female |            3 |
| Max           | Male   |            0 |
+---------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Impossible to answer your question without knowing the DDL of the tables involved.   Give enough information to reproduce it.

Comment: we wont know neither without the data or the result. You could get right result by luck.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you did not want to use a `RIGHT JOIN`, and that was what was giving you back records that were "not working". As the `RIGHT JOIN` would likely give you duplicates in this scenario, generally speaking (unless you want to see the off-set data), you need a `GROUP BY` for this type of joining.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I made edits in the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: The query wouldn't execute without the `right join` line.  Did you also change `ON` to `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group you count by cust_id:

```
WITH
    aset
    AS
        (  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT tran_date) trans_count, cust_id
             FROM transactions
         GROUP BY cust_id)
SELECT *
  FROM aset INNER JOIN customer ON cust_id = customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
select c.*, t.Nooftrans
from customer c outer apply (
     select count(distinct t.cust_id) as [Basket Count]
     from Transactions t
     where t.cust_id = c.customer_Id
     group by t.tran_date;
) t;
```

However, this assumes `tran_date` has reasonable format else you would need to use `cast/convert()` function accordingly.

Now, i would re-write your first approach as :

```
select c.*,
          (select COUNT(distinct t.cust_id) 
           from Transactions t
           where t.cust_id = c.customer_Id
           group by t.tran_date
          ) as [Basket Count]
from Customer c;
```